# Ajax in Laravel not working

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel-5.6

I am trying to achieve simple Ajax call in my web application, unfortunately it is not working.

**Html code**

```
<li id="decorative_items">
    Decorative Items
</li>
```

**Ajax code:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var id = 2; /* This has nothing to do with the code */
$("#decorative_items").bind("click", function() {
    alert("click event fired"); /*This is working*/
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:'/getDecorativeItems',
        data: {'id' : id},
        success:function(response) {
            alert("foo");
        }
    }); 
});
});
```

**routes/web.php**

```
Route::post('/getDecorativeItems', 'ajaxController@fetchDecorativeItems');
```

**ajaxController.php**

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\DispatchesJobs;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as BaseController;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Validation\ValidatesRequests;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\AuthorizesRequests;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ajaxController extends Controller
{
    function fetchDecorativeItems(Request $request) {
        $msg = "Reached Controller";
        return response()->json(array('msg'=> $msg), 200);
    }
}
```

I have read all the answers to related questions and other online posts but I am unable to find the error.

**Note:** The code is working fine, there is no syntax error but I am unable to achieve the intended output. The intended output I am looking for is alerting "foo" using Ajax

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please give us some more information than simply 'it doesn't work'. Check the console to see what the exact response is.

Comment: Please go read [ask]. At the moment it is absolutely unclear what kind of problem you are having, because you basically only told us that you had one, but not anything actually useful besides that.

Comment: The actual problem I am trying to implement has nothing to do with this. I am simply trying to achieve Ajax functionality in it. I am trying to alert "foo" using Ajax. That's it

Comment: Instead of alerting string 'foo' try to console.log(response) and also add error : function (response) { console.log(response) } in your ajax. Then in your console check for the message.

Answer (score 0):

Turn on your `chrome devtoo`l, check on `network -> XHR` in list of your `XHR request`, click on your `ajax request` (Case your ajax request fase, it has red color )  ->  preview to see what really happen, if somethings wrong on your Laravel backend code, it also show here. 
See the image bellow:

[image]

Hope this helfull, don't debug by print an `alert()`

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution.

I was missing CSRF in my Ajax function call

```
headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')},
```